# how to add foreign key constraint to a column in sql server across multiple database?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, t-sql

I got another problem while assigning the foreign key constraint to a column across multiple database? Any Idea with example!

Thanks in Advance,
Shashra

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem Adding Foreign Key Between Two Databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452132/problem-adding-foreign-key-between-two-databases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a trigger to do this.