# SQL Server Foreign Keys across database boundaries - techniques for enforcement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, security

I have two separate SQL Server 2005 databases (on the same server)

- security database
- main application database
- The security database has a  **user table** with everything needed to authenticate.  -
- The application database has a **person table** with extended user details. There is a 1-1 mapping between the security database user table and the application database person table.

I want to enforce a mapping between the user and the person table. I'm assuming that foreign keys can't be mapped across databases thus I am wondering what to do to enforce the integrity of the relationship.

Comment: The problem is, the unit of recovery with SQL Server is the database - so what do you do if the two databases are restored with inconsistent data (e.g. from different points in time), or if one database is offline?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Foreign Key relationship between two Databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452132/add-foreign-key-relationship-between-two-databases)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Cross database foreign keys are indeed not supported

```
    Msg 1763, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
    Cross-database foreign key references are not supported.
```

If you really want to enforce the referential integrity on the database side you will have to rely on triggers. (which I don't recommend)

to make your code more maintainable you could create synonyms for the tables you want to check referential integrity on.

```
      CREATE SYNONYM myTable FOR otherdatabase.dbo.myTable;
```

This would be to make the "manual" checks easier, as you can not create foreign keys on a synonym.

Comment: Are you implying that a foreign key constraint can reference a table in another database by using a synonym as an intermediary?

Answer (score 5):

It's a lot of work but you may think about merging those two databases into a single database.  If you want a logical difference between objects within the database, you can use a [schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387.aspx).