# Create new database or use the existing ASP.NET Identity database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been teaching myself ASP.NET MVC5 development and I have a problem determining the best practice in this situation.

I am using the ASP.NET Identity system which created a database for me. Now I want to add more tables and things to it. Should I create a new database or should I add to the existing database? What is best practice in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

**Use the same database**.

There's no real reason to separate the different types of data into different databases.  And if you *were* to split up the different data, that would complicate a lot of things unnecessarily (i.e. [unable to have foreign key constraints across databases, making referential integrity a nightmare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166641/sql-server-foreign-keys-across-database-boundaries-techniques-for-enforcement)).  And especially if the multiple databases don't live in the same instance, you'll deal with an even larger headache.  Other things that would pose extra consideration would be having to include ownership chaining planning across the database.

In short, I don't see a reason to split the data into a different database.  And there are a few reasons that would make multiple databases a pain, so I'd steer clear from that without an actual justifiable reason.

Answer (score 0):

try using same database rather creating new database for each new table.
One database can have as many tables as you need to have.