# Cross-database foreign key 

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I have two database `DB1` with table `TBL1`, `DB2` with table `TBL2`, and I need a foreign key in `[TBL1]` (in `DB1`) to reference the other table `[TBL2]` (in `DB2`).

When I try to create them through SQL, I received the following error message :

> Msg 1763, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Cross-database foreign key references are not supported. Foreign key 'SAMPLEDB..VENDOR'.

Is that possible to refer foreign key in external database?

If possible, please give solution for this. If not possible, please suggest some alternate way.

Comment: I guess this is for SQL-Server. Which version?

Comment: Check this (identical) question: [Problem Adding Foreign Key Between Two Databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452132/problem-adding-foreign-key-between-two-databases). I like the answer by Cade Roux.

Comment: I guess the error message tells you that this is not possible.