# Move a table from one database to another database SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a database `DB_1` which has an empty table `T1` with 5 columns.

I want to move this table to another database `DB_2` on the same SQL Server.

I have tried to use this command:

```
alter table DB_1.T1 rename DB_2.T1
```

but this showing error.

> *Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Incorrect syntax near 'rename'.*

Please help.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If the databases are on same server then do it like this,

```
select * into DB_2.T1 from DB_1.[dbo].[T1]
```

if you have databases on different servers than you have to create a linked server.

On second thought you can generate **"create tables scripts"** and run them on second database

Comment: Thanks . This creates the table in other database DB_@ with same column names BUT the constarints and indexes are not copied. Can you tell me how to proceed further.

Comment: if you have to copy constarints and index too then better use SSMS,http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/17a16dc4-dcf1-4de8-baba-6949c55a4c5d/

Answer (score 34):

In `SQL Server Management Studio` you have `Import and Export Wizard` :

1. Right click on db name(`DB_2`)
2. Tasks
3. Import Data
4. Choose data source (`DB_1`)
5. Choose destination (`DB_2`)
6. Choose `copy data from one ore more tables`
7. Choose your table (`T1`)
8. Finish

Comment: yes this works, but `identity` and `foreign key` references are removed, is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

With help of my office friends , this is the solution I figured out.

1. In object Explorer , go to source database and select table to move.
2. Right click , Script Table As -> CREATE TO -> New Query Editor Window. This opens query window with the SQL queries specifying schema , indexes , constraints on the table.
3. You can change table name in CREATE TABLE section and make other changes...
4. Change database name in first line `USE <DATABASE>` to Target database and execute the the query.

Thanks.

Comment: This creates a table structure, but the data still remains in the old table

Comment: @Jonny This is no problem because he said that his source table was empty. His whole question doesn't make much sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

If your table have too many data you should migrate in loop so you don't use too many memory during the transaction, see [Log Space](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-sqlperf-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Create the table structure using the Object Explorer like other answers

Check if there isn't any [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16) on the table, second result column "Computed", if you have computed columns you need to write every column name in the `OUTPUT` because SQL will try to storage the column as a value:

```
EXEC DB_2..SP_HELP T1
```

You can copy the columns names from this result if you need to specify them, then you can create a loop like this:

```
DECLARE @R INT = 100000
WHILE @R = 100000 BEGIN
    
    BEGIN TRAN
    
        -- Delete top N rows
        DELETE TOP (@R) DB_1..T1
        -- Output the result
        OUTPUT DELETED.*
        -- Inserting the result into the following table
        INTO DB_2..T1

        -- Setting the variable equals to the number of rows affected
        SET @R = @@ROWCOUNT
    COMMIT
END
```

If your table have a identity column use this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT DB_2..T1 ON
```

And in the INTO statement you need to write the name of every column of your table, is just a way for MSSQL be sure that you know what you are doing:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT DB_2..T1 ON

DECLARE @R INT = 100000
WHILE @R = 100000 BEGIN
    
    BEGIN TRAN
    
        -- Delete top N rows
        DELETE TOP (@R) DB_1..T1
        -- Output the result
        OUTPUT
            DELETED.COL1
            ,DELETED.COL2
        -- Inserting the result into the following table
        INTO DB_1..T2 (col1, col2)

        -- Setting the variable equals to the number of rows affected
        SET @R = @@ROWCOUNT
    COMMIT
END

SET IDENTITY_INSERT DB_2..T1 OFF
```

Sadly, you can't have a `FOREIGN KEY` from one database to another, you can either move other tables to the same database then create the foreign keys or [create triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452132/add-foreign-key-relationship-between-two-databases) to keep some integrity, not the best practice