# Add Foreign Key Contraint between Tables in different Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add Foreign Key relationship between two Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452132/add-foreign-key-relationship-between-two-databases)

What i know is that i can add a foregin key constraint, so that one column in table A can reference to another column in table B using :

```
CONSTRAINT fk FOREIGN KEY (column) REFERENCES toTable(toColumn)
```

but here both tables are in the same database. I want to know if i can reference to  table in another database. For instance , i have two databases: databaseA and databaseB, when i want to associate them, i prefer adding some table in databaseA reference to another table in databaseB. But i don't know how. Something like :

```
CONSTRAINT fk FOREIGN KEY (column) REFERENCES [databaseB].[toTable](toColumn)
```

doesn't work.

Comment: It is database,not schema. My example may be not accurate,so i have changed them to databaseA and databaseB.

Comment: Might help, looks horrible though - http://dba010.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/how-to-create-database-link-in-sql-server-2005/

Comment: if your server is `SQL server`, you might want to read this.[Adding Foreign Key Between Two Databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452132/problem-adding-foreign-key-between-two-databases)

Comment: Yes, that is my situation. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: This is usually a sign that the two databases ought to be merged. Otherwise, taking consistent backups becomes a far larger challenge.