# Cannot build Relationship between two tables from different databases

Tags: grails, grails-orm, multi-database

I have the following use case:

- `[User.groovy]`: is mapped to **user** table in  **auth** mysql Database .
- `[Project.groovy]` : is mapped to **project** table in **pm** mysql database

When i add this relationship between the 2 classes

```
class Project {

   User addedBy;
  //..................

}
```

i've got this error :

> An association from the table project refers to an unmapped class:
>   abdennour.auth.User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can't have primary-foreign key relationships between [tables in different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452132/add-foreign-key-relationship-between-two-databases).

Answer (score 0):

Basing on @Donal Answer , i think on trick to resolve this issue :

Instead of :

```
class Project {

   User addedBy;
  //..................

}
```

we will have:

```
class Project {

   Long addedById;
  //..................


   User addedBy(){

      User.get(this.addedById)  
   }

}
```

this means, we solve this issue in domain layer