# Inner join between different database

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I want to create a table using the following script in a database called `DeltaDatabase`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OutStatus](
[Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[OutId] [int] NOT NULL,
[StatusType] [varchar](255) NULL,
[StatusDate] [datetime] NULL)
```

I would then like to `INNER JOIN` a column into this table from another database called `CoreDatabase`.

The column name is `sourceId` from the table `Client`. So in other words `OutId` needs to be foreign key of `SourceId`.

How do I join that column into my `OutStatus` table from the other database using the create table script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic syntax to retrieve data would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CoreDatabase.dbo.Client c
INNER JOIN DeltaDatabase.dbo.OutStatus os ON c.SourceId = os.OutId
```

You need to fully qualify the tables name with: `DatabaseName.Schema.TableName`

You may wish to limit the columns or add a where clause to reduce the data that is returned.

As far as creating a foreign key across databases goes, [**it's not something you can do**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452132/add-foreign-key-relationship-between-two-databases). You would have to use triggers or some other logic to maintain referential integrity between the primary and foreign keys.

Comment: thanks for the reply, can this be done within the create table query or should i first create the table? the query needs to be part of the creat table query

Comment: Well if you're going to write code to manage the data integrity, be it a trigger or some other method, then you won't be able to create them without the table existing first. If you try to reference an object that doesn't exist in a trigger you would get an error when you try to create it. So create the table first, then code against it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query

```
Select * from DeltaDatabase.dbo.OutStatus OUS
Inner Join CoreDatabase.dbo.Client CL on OUS.OutId=CL.sourceId
```