# Is it possible to have alternative relationship in jpa

Tags: java, jpa

I have one @Entity class "Survey" which is having @ManyToOne relationship with "ProductSourced" @Entity class. Now "ProductSourced" can exist in same database or can come from a different database. Is it possible to create @JoinColumn such a way that first it searches in db1 and if it didnot get in db1 then it seaches primary key in db2?

Comment: You can't have relationships (foreign keys) between different databases as far as I know. Maybe you can do the join you want in a custom query

Comment: Workarounds are possible yet risky and frail: see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452132/add-foreign-key-relationship-between-two-databases