# Match ID between two different databases in Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I would like to try how to match between two different databases in Laravel.

I am using Laravel in 5.7 version.

To simplify my databases, let's say a table is called Employee in **DB1** and the other table is called Worker in **DB2**.

A primary key in both tables is ID which should be matched.

If Laravel doesn't allow that, I am also willing to know how to match in mySql.

Comment: I am a little confused - Laravel is a PHP framework.  Isn't this a MySQL question?

Comment: @Nelles If I can handle with it in Laravel, I would like to know how to do that. if can't, I am also likely to try it in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoted from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4452150/6917318)

> You would need to manage the referential constraint across databases
>   using a Trigger.
>   ***************** Basically you create an insert, update trigger to verify the existence of the Key in the Primary key table.  If the key
>   does not exist then revert the insert or update and then handle the
>   exception.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> Create Trigger dbo.MyTableTrigger ON dbo.MyTable, After Insert, Update
> As
> Begin
>
>    If NOT Exists(select PK from OtherDB.dbo.TableName where PK in (Select FK from inserted) BEGIN
>       -- Handle the Referential Error Here
>    END
>
> END
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **Edited:**  Just to clarify.  This is not the best approach with enforcing referential integrity.  Ideally you would want both tables
>   in the same db but if that is not possible.  Then the above is a
>   potential work around for you.

---

As mentioned in the quoted answer, the best approach would be to have the tables in the same database. 
If you can do that then simply add a `foreign key` between them:

The `FOREIGN KEY constraint` is a key used to link two tables together.

A `FOREIGN KEY` is a field (or collection of fields) in one table that refers to the `PRIMARY KEY` in another table.

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
);
```

So in this example `column` named `PersonID` located in `table` named `Orders` will link via a `foreign key` to the `column` named `PersonID` located in `table` named `Persons`.

Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_foreign_key.asp) or [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)