# Can we create foreign key without models in Django?

Tags: sql-server, django

I am using **SQL Server database and Django**. I have a Database named as **Person Database** and Other database as **Student Database**. In **Person database I created models**, but in **Student database there are no models** because the tables and data are already existing. So I am getting data of Student database using Pyodbc. Now I am creating a new model in Person database where I need to create a **foreign key** for student database. Can anyone help me out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a Foreign Key relation in between tables of different databases. Foreign Key relations can only be created between tables of the same database. There is a workaround on this, although it is not recommended. Please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4452150/7183805).