# Is it possible to set foreign keys between tables of two different databases in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Is it possible to set foreign keys between tables of two different databases in laravel? it's possible

Comment: Check out this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452132/add-foreign-key-relationship-between-two-databases 

Laravel is just a framework using some relational database under the hood.

Comment: You have to check first if you database supports it.

Answer (score 1):

**Cross database foreign keys** hasn't much to do with Laravel actually.

MySQL (at least with InnoDB) does support foreign key constraints across multiple databases. You just have to specify the database with the dot notation:

Regarding the Laravel schema builder, this should work:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('main_db.users');
//                                                ^^^^^^^
```

If you get an error, check if the column types are the same.

> You can't reference varchar to int or vice-versa, keys have to be of
> same type

Go through [Foreign key cross database](https://laravel.io/forum/02-27-2014-foreign-key-cross-database) for more details

Answer (score 0):

IF, and only if your underlying database supports it, then there should be a way to translate this business rule to a Laravel app.

Maybe not using their fancy built-in ORM. But surely it's possible to write a migration for it using `DB::statement` or even `DB::unprepared`. But as the code for such a setup is not database agnostic this is against best practices, but not impossible.

You then must configure two (or more) connections, one for each database and use the property `$connection` on you models to tell Laravel on which database each model is. You will be able to even use Eloquent relations this way between models in different databases.