# How to add a columns from another table of another database

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I add a new column to a table? This column located in another table from another database. I also need it as an 'on update cascade'. So far I have no idea how to do it.

This is an example query that adds a new columns top exist table:

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD descriptions VARCHAR (255);
```

But this example refers to a hardcoded column.

Comment: Create a trigger in the other database to update this one? Seems a strange design...

Comment: Why do you think it is strange?

Comment: @Dale K yeah....like this post shows, you cannot have foreign keys to another database; you have to make a trigger for this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452132/add-foreign-key-relationship-between-two-databases

Comment: Strange, because its usually harder and more complex to try and sync data that it is to query it when required.

Comment: @Dale K - Are you suggesting using a simple query?

Comment: Can you just create a `view` that joins to the table in the other database and just query the view?